# Change x86 to x64 dlls in production environment for ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, dll, production

I have an ASP.NET application that I am currently developing in C#.

The application needs a set of reference (dlls) to work. At development phase I need to use the x86 (32 bits) libraries but when I put the application in production I need to substitute the libraries with the x64 (64 bits) version.

Is it correct and safe to deploy the sytem in my IIS7 (Server 2008) as it is in Visual Studio (so working with x86 libraries) and then change the x86 libraries with the x64 directly in production environment (by copy pasting)? If that is not the case may you please suggest a more clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all cases you should test/develop with the same version as you deploy on production. So in development you should compile for x64 if your production server is x64. Otherwise you have the risk of error when you go to production. For example you can use a x86 lib which you do not compile yourself. The you will only notice this on production, which is a little late.

The way to go is to make all environments the same.